# Pass a variable to python including hash # or special characters - Error message: Login failed for user 'test1'

Tags: python, sql-server

I am trying to run a query from a container

When I use below method to pass the variables it is working fine.

```
import os
username = 'test1' 
password = 'foo]#BAR' 
database = "master"
server="xyz.com"
query="some random query"
os.system('mssql-cli -U '+username+' -P '+password+' -d'+database+' -S '+server+' --query "'+query+'"')
```

but when I pass the environment variable and run it, I hit below error
export password=foo]#BAR

```
import os
username = 'test1' 
password = os.getenv('target_env')
database = "master"
server="xyz.com"
query="some random query"
os.system('mssql-cli -U '+username+' -P '+str(password)+' -d'+database+' -S '+server+' --query "'+query+'"')
```

Anyone can help to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: escape the parameters you pass to OS using `"`s

Comment: Why invoke `mssql-cli` here at all? Why not use a library like pyodbc or pymssql?

Comment: Thanks flor the reply, there are some limitation over adding them on our container 
and using ```"``` did not work. same issue

Comment: @Hoomaan you should probably create a new question around that password issue specifically. I have no problems passing in `- DB_PASSWORD=foo]#BAR` via a `docker-compose.yml` file, picking it up correctly in Python with `password = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')` and then connecting successfully to SQL Server using pyodbc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue,
I run the python through a bash file, it worked when I run it directly from my local.
For some reason (not sure why) bash changed the password variable to a different value